# Removing a few special characters from an NSString for a filename PDF attached to an email

Tags: ios, regex, nsstring, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am working with attachments in emails using `MFMailComposeViewController` and the file name of the pdf is based on the user's input for the event names, so this could be John Wedding, or John's Wedding.

I want to remove any special characters from the name of the file.

In my code, I've done this:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"'#%^&{}[]~|\/?.<," options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *string = self.occasion.title;
NSString *modifiedString = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length]) withTemplate:@""];

NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(%@).pdf", modifiedString];
```

With this, it removes the apostrophe from my filename if it's John's Wedding, but if I have a hash or any of the other symbols in there, it doesn't remove those in the file name.

I've seen a few stack overflow examples online but they all look extremely complicated; I know exactly which symbols I want to remove from the file name.

Any guidance would be really appreciated.

Comment: u want to remove all special characters in file

Comment: Just in the file name. So if the filename is John's W#dding & %^.pdf for example, I want to remove all special characters in the filename except Johns Wedding.pdf

Comment: might be better to have a white list of accepted chars

Comment: Thanks @gwillie that does indeed make sense actually; how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I dont know what chars you want, but lets start with the most obvious: `[a-zA-Z0-9{}()\[\]'"+-]`. This represents alphabetic (case-insensitive), numeric and the following chars `{}()[]'"+-`. You get the point. Trying to account for every character you dont want is generally harder then specifying valid chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *textString = @"abcd334%$^%^%80)(*^ujikl";

//this is for remove the specified characters
NSCharacterSet *chs = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"'#%^&{}[]/~|\?.<,"];
NSString *resultString = [[textString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:chs] componentsJoinedByString:@""];

//this is for get the specified characters
NSCharacterSet *chs1 = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"'#%^&{}[]/~|\?.<,"] invertedSet];
NSString *resultString1 = [[textString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:chs1] componentsJoinedByString:@""];
NSLog(@"tex : %@",resultString);
NSLog(@"reverse string : %@",resultString1);
```

out put:

text : abcd334$80)(*ujikl

reverse string : %^%^%^